# How to generate transpose-like matrix without using any built-in function and without using loops?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Is not exactly like a matrix transpose. I'm using python and trying using matrix transformations but I can't without loops, I'm using numpy, is there any solution just using matrix operations or vectorized functions?.

For example:

[image]

To this

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the below matrix is the actual [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of the upper one? Your example is flipped along the "wrong diagonal", it seems.

Comment: @heltonbiker it's not. The transformation is `test[:,::-1].T[:,::-1]`

Comment: Why can't you use built-in operation?

Comment: I don't understand your objection to `.T`; transpose is a matrix operation, which fulfils your `is there any solution just using matrix operations`.

Comment: Idk why but the teacher is like a crazy mathematician and don't like that kind of functions like [].T

Comment: @droooze your solution is amazing! but the teacher is like an old man and don't like the built-in functions :(

Comment: Is this a homework assignment to teach you matrix transforms, or is it really just a matter of your teaching prefering to not use a matrix transpose?

Comment: the course is linear algebra, and it's a problem from a pset but it say's no loops and no built-in functions, I know it sounds crazy but I think i make something similar with R before

Comment: You need to be more specific what qualifies as a "builtin function". Dot product? Accessing elements? Matrix transpose? In that case there are exactly zero methods left that allow you to work with your matrix, and the task becomes impossible to solve.

Comment: You can use ideas from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299901/finding-a-matrix-representation-of-the-transpose-transformation) - that shouldn't be considered "cheating".

Comment: thanks for your responses guys! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to rotate this 180 degrees then transpose. How about:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]])

np.rot90(x, 2).T

>>> array([[9, 6, 3],
           [8, 5, 2],
           [7, 4, 1]])
```

Comment: Is there any matrix transformation to do this? just with matrices, I do the same but he doesn't want to see any function like rot90 or T, and thanks for the response! :)

Comment: What exactly are you allowed to use? Matrix products?

Comment: I think you are confused about what a "vectorized operation" is. All of the solutions, including `test[:,::-1].T[:,::-1]` are vectorized operations!

Comment: I'm agreed with that, and that solution is amazing but older people think use .T is like cheating (myb he comes from C language)

Answer (score 1):

Here are is a way that only uses indexing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(['abcdefghi']).view('U1').reshape(3, 3)
>>> a
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f'],
       ['g', 'h', 'i']], dtype='<U1')
>>> 
>>> a[[2,1,0],[[2],[1],[0]]]
array([['i', 'f', 'c'],
       ['h', 'e', 'b'],
       ['g', 'd', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

If you do not want to hardcode the indices you'll have to use some kind of builtin. Either Python builtins:

```
>>> a[list(reversed(range(3))), list(zip(reversed(range(3))))]
array([['i', 'f', 'c'],
       ['h', 'e', 'b'],
       ['g', 'd', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

or numpy

```
>>> a[np.ogrid[2:-1:-1,2:-1:-1][::-1]]
array([['i', 'f', 'c'],
       ['h', 'e', 'b'],
       ['g', 'd', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

Note that all these methods do a non-lazy transpose, meaning that the resulting array is C contiguous.

Comment: I like your last; it's the `ix_` indexing but with the `I,J` switched.  Or `meshgrid` with `indexing='xy'`.  I was stuck on trying to do the transpose without `transpose`.